# Transition Issue Unknown Cause

Tags: prolog

I am trying to create a NFA to describe it with states which accepts "y|x*"

This is what I have tried so far:

```
acpt(State, [A]).
acpt(State, []) :- acpt(State).
acpt(State, InputList) :- InputList = [A],
                             transition(State, X).
```

When given the input

```
acpt(q0, [x,y]).
```

I'm looking for it to return t

```
true
```

When given

```
acpt(q0, [x,x,y]).
```

it should return

```
false
```

The code I have produces a few errors and I was wondering if I can get some help. Thx.

Comment: changing the initial code without explicit references make difficult to post coherent answers, and to follow the overall question, since the context is hidden in edit history...

Comment: You have `InputList = [A]` in your third clause, but `A` isn't referenced anywhere else. So you are getting a *warning* about a singleton variable. What does `transition/2` do? And when you say, *The code I have produces a few errors*, what are the errors?

Comment: For the purpose of making my post concise and easier to understand/ easier for readers to help answer a particular part of the question. Thank you for answering @CapelliC

Answer (score 1):

I comment the corrections required to get

```
1 ?- acpt(q0, [x,y]).
true 
.

2 ?- acpt(q0, [x,x,y]).
false.
```

working code:

```
% totally useless:
% acpt(State, [A|B]).

% typo: of course, we need acptng/1
% acpt(State, []) :- acpt(State).

acpt(State, []) :- acptng(State).
acpt(State, [A|B]) :-
    transition(State, X, A),
    acpt(X, B).
```

now, apart the test input being working, I must say that I cannot see the 'epsilon rule' implementation. IIRC, a NFA should allows to change state *without* consuming input.

*edit*

a trace

```
4 ?- leash(-all),trace,acpt(q0, [x,x,x]).
   Call: (7) so:acpt(q0, [x, x, x])
   Call: (8) so:transition(q0, _G1431, x)
   Exit: (8) so:transition(q0, q3, x)
   Call: (8) so:acpt(q3, [x, x])
   Call: (9) so:transition(q3, _G1431, x)
   Exit: (9) so:transition(q3, q3, x)
   Call: (9) so:acpt(q3, [x])
   Call: (10) so:transition(q3, _G1431, x)
   Exit: (10) so:transition(q3, q3, x)
   Call: (10) so:acpt(q3, [])
   Call: (11) so:acptng(q3)
   Exit: (11) so:acptng(q3)
   Exit: (10) so:acpt(q3, [])
   Exit: (9) so:acpt(q3, [x])
   Exit: (8) so:acpt(q3, [x, x])
   Exit: (7) so:acpt(q0, [x, x, x])
true 
.
```

Comment: yes, it does: `?- acpt(q0, [x,x,x]). true.` I've shown only the change wrt the buggy code. Please consider instead the final note in my answer...

Comment: indeed, acpt(q0,[x,x,x]). is true

Comment: The code in screenshot seems fine, what I cannot see is the reload of the source... Trace your code, using the 'instructions' in my answer